# Missing #/definitions/HttpError in Swashbuckle implementation

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, swashbuckle.examples

I am working on a code base generating a swagger document correctly.

All of the endpoints have HTTP responses which are referencing #/definitions/HttpError. However, HTTPError is missing from my swagger JSON documentation.

I want to include HTTPError in the "definitions" element of the json doc, but I cannot do so. How can that be included?

Example:

```
"/User": {
"get": {
"tags": [
"user"
],
"summary": "Get the user information",
"description": "User",
"operationId": "User_Get_GET",
"consumes": [],
"produces": [
"application/json",
"text/json",
"text/html",
"application/octet-stream",
"application/xml",
"text/xml"
],
"responses": {
"200": {
"description": "Successfully returns the system information",
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/SystemInfoDto"
}
},
"403": {
"description": "Unauthorized",
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/HttpError"
}
},
"404": {
"description": "Not Found",
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/HttpError"
}
},
"409": {
"description": "Another user has modified this record, please re-retrieve and try again",
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/HttpError"
}
}
}
}
},
```

Comment: if HttpError is a defined model inside your code then it should have already available. something is not adding up. can you add the definitions of GET /User method and HttpError model

Comment: Thanks for your response @CodingMytra.

I was expecting the definitions to get added automatically as there is this inbuilt HttpError class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httperror?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I tried adding my own model and that works completely fine. Should the inbuilt one not get added in the definition element?

Comment: it should be, which version of .net core and swashbuckle you are using.

Comment: @CodingMytra netCore version is 6.0.101 and swashbuckle version is 5.6.0

Comment: is this HttpError part of ASP.NET core 6, I see it is defined in 2.2. can you put your code also.